# How to make discord bot ping users using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am coding a discord bot and for one of the commands I want the bot to ping the user that sent the command. I'm using python 3.6.6

Answer (score 6):

Here is one example how you can ping (mention) the user who sent a specific message (command):

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == '$the_ping_cmd':
            await message.channel.send('Pinging {}'.format(message.author.mention))

client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == '$the_ping_cmd':
            await message.channel.send(f"Pinging {message.author.mention}")

client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```