# How to ping members from a string discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm getting strings of game-chat from a server and I need to check if a user is mentioned in that string and if he is, I need to find him on the server and mention him because I can't just send the string as it is as it's not mentioning him.

Here's a simple example:

```
socket_str = "Hey this is a ping test for @TheBeast"
```

I need to check for tags on that string (**@**) , then get the name separated so `TheBeast` , then I need to go over the members in the servers and find a *member object* with that name and build a final fstring that contains the string before the mention, and with the mention.

so it will look the same but the bot will actually mention this user.

This was the simplest example, but there are so many edge cases that I can't deal with, for example, what if the the person has spaces in his name, how do you know when the name ends? Here's is the most complicated example I could make:

```
socket_str = "Hey I'm looking for @The New Beast is he online?, or @Newly Born Beast or @someone that doesnt exists is on?"
```

I'm looking for a different approach for this, I could share what I wrote so far which is a lot but honestly it's so complex code even I don't understand from it much anymore

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639644/how-to-make-discord-bot-ping-users-using-discord-py
I think the this post has the answer?

Comment: not really related to my question, the users on my question are not sending the messages, I am getting them into a string from a socket.

Comment: Oh, trying replacing the name with user_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually very non-trivial. You've already said it yourself

> "if the the person has spaces in his name, how do you know when the name ends?"

The only option I can think of to **reliably** check if a username (containing spaces) exists is to iteratively check each combination of spaced words as long as a certain semantic criteria is met.
In Discord, the only restrictions usernames have is that it can be at max 32 characters long. AFAIK you can have every symbol, emoji whatsoever in your name...

---

To illustrate, the statements would look something like this

```
string = "Hello @This is a username! Whats up?"

# is "This" a username?
# yes -> great! | no -> is "This is" a username?
# yes -> great! | no -> is "This is a" a username?
# yes -> great! | no -> is "This is a username!" a username?
# ...
```

However, this is also another edge case. `This is a username` is a valid user, but by spliting with spaces the program would look for `This is a username!`, which isn't  valid. So as far as I can tell, the best option to say **for sure**, if a username is valid is to actually check for each character until the max length of Discord usernames.

---

This could be implemented like so

```
string = "Hello @This is a username! Whats up?"
potentialUsernames = string.split("@") # Split string into potential usernames
del potentialUsernames [0] # Delete first element, as it is definitely not a username

for potentialUsername in potentialUsernames: # for every potential username, do
    for run, letter in enumerate(potentialUsername): # for every letter in every potential username, do
        checkUsername = potentialUsername[:(run+1)]
        if run > 32: 
            break # break out of this loop as there cant be a username here anymore
        potentialMember = guild.get_member_named(checkUsername) # check if potential username exists
        if potentialMember != None: # BOOM, we found a member!
            string = string.replace("@" + checkUsername, potentialMember.mention) # replace the username with real mention in string
            break # break because the user was already found
```

The output of `print(string)` would be

```
"Hello <@!1234567891011121314>! Whats up?"
```

yes.. this is how mentions would look in text-form, if you didn't know. The long number would be the user-id, however `Member.mention` already constructs this for you!
In this code, `guild` will have to be the guild object, of which you want to get the members from.

---

Now, what this code does is checking every potential username split by `@`, and check for every possible length until the next `@`, or Discords restriction of 32 characters.
I.e.

```
# is "T" a username?
# yes -> great | no -> is "Th" a username?
# yes -> great | no -> is "Thi" a username?
# ...
```

---

As a side note, this method should work with any amount of mentions!